# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint superuser

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm writing a site on django. And I ran into a problem, when I want to add a superuser, the following error occurs:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (pbkdf2_sha256$390000$gajFrJerChyUlrAwZWzfkS$gmZ4GQTavfwqlV5jaPl+..., null, t, admin_dima, , , t, t, 2023-01-07 22:12:28.
743122+00, null, , dima1@gmail.com, , ).
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a model that inherits from AbstractUser
Here is my model:

```
class JobseekerRegisterInfo(AbstractUser):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    hashed_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

And I commented for a while in the settings.py file and the main urls.py file the link to the admin page, and before that, how to create a superuser, I uncommented it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [automatic primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for `id`. For example, [`models.BigAutoField` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) is a 64-bit integer under the hood:

```python
class JobseekerRegisterInfo(AbstractUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```